# ARCore session/anchor tracking while displaying a rewardedAd/Interstitial using Admob for Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, admob, arcore

ARCore pauses session and loses Anchor when a rewarded ad is displayed

Our game is built on top of ARCore plane tracking APIs and uses rewarded ads for monetization. ARCore loses the anchor when the Android device changes context to display an ad (interstitial or rewarded ads).

We'd like to know if there's any workaround to retain the anchor tracking when the ad modal is shown.

App is build using Unity 2019 and ARCore SDK 1.9 and the latest version of the Google Mobile Ads Unity Plugin v3.16

Answer (score 0):

For the time being, the following workaround has been implemented:

1. The SDK has been updated to prevent automatic anchor children
   visibility updates when tracking state changes. (Anchor.cs).
2. While ad is being displayed, ARSession is paused.
3. When the Ad is Closed, ARSession is set back to tracking.
4. 3 second grace period is given after ARSession is back to tracking to try locate the anchor/plane, otherwise, we update the state so the user can rescan the area and reset the anchor in a new position.